# How to skip parallel branch in camunda

Tags: camunda

I have the following camunda flow

[image]

Sometimes an error might happen in any of the 8 service tasks. In that case I would like to skip
the service tasks on that branch that come next to the one that throws the error, log the error and let the other branch complete successfully.
Currently if an error happens in one of the branches the flow will hang.
The flow will also hang if there is a failure in both branches.
What is the best way to address this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can catch the error and log that and continue the flow of execution.

Something like this:
[image: Something like this]